# Getting meteor to re-render a route for "new document"

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I've got a route "/new/" for new documents. I had a button for going there and event code that looked like

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     window.location.href = "/new/";
  },
});
```

This worked but I don't want meteor to re-load the page which is what happened. Instead I wanted to just render the route. So I tried this

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     Router.go("/new/");
  },
});
```

Now absolutely nothing happens. Even if I'm on another route that uses the same top level template all that happens is the URL changed but the route is not actually re-rendered.

I tried fixing this with a Tracker.Dependency

```
var someDummyDep = new Tracker.Dependency; // also tried Deps.Dependency();

Template.form.onCreated = function() {
  var instance = this;
  instance.autorun(function() {
    someDummyDep.depend();
  });
});

Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     someDummyDep.changed();
     Router.go("/new/");
  },
});
```

I wasn't sure how else to make the template dependent but since I have other templates with onCreated functions that use reactive stuff I thought this might work. It didn't no change. Nothing happens, nothing gets re-rendered.

The actual route just looks like this

```
Router.route('/new/', function() {
  this.render('form');
});
```

I tried changing the route to this

```
Router.route('/new/', {
  action: function() {
    this.render('form');
  },
  data: function() {
    someDummyDep.depend();
  },
});
```

and this

```
Router.route('/new/', {
  action: function() {
    this.render('form');
  },
  data: function() {
    someDummyDep.depend();
    return Math.random();  // ?? maybe if the data changes?
  },
});
```

I also tried this

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     someDummyDep.changed();
     Router.go("/new/", {}, {hash: Math.random().toString()});
  },
});
```

Which should set the URL to something like `/new/#3243543623432` but it doesn't set the hash even though the docs say it should.

What should I do to get meteor/iron-router to re-render?

Answer (score 0):

to solve your first problem give name to your route and call it,this will not reload the page

**Router Js**

```
Router.route('/new/', function() {
  this.render('form');
},{
  name:'new'
);
```

**js**

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     Router.go('new')
  },
});
```

also if you want to pass some id or anything else

**Router Js**

```
Router.route('/new/:something', function() {
  this.render('form');
},{
  name:'new'
);
```

**js**

```
Template.form.events({
  "click #new": function() {
     Router.go('new',{something:123})
  },
});
```

or just some hash

```
Router.route('/new', function() {
  this.render('form');
},{
  name:'new'
);

Template.form.events({
   "click #new": function() {
      Router.go('new',{},{hash: Math.random().toString()});
   },
});
```